# Attaching datepicker to column of new row on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, html-table, onclick

I am trying to add a new row on button click. In my new row there is one Textbox with which I want to bind datepicker but not able to. Please help me to resolve this issue.
HTML Code

```
<table>
     <tr>
     <td><button type="button" onClick ="addRow(this)">Add</button></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="installDate" value="" class ="date"/> </td>        
     </tr>
</table>
```

Java Script:

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
$('.date').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker();
});
});

function addRow(btn) {         
    var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var table = parentRow.parentNode;
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var lastRow = table.rows[rowCount - 1];
    var rowClone = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
    table.appendChild(rowClone);
    $('.date', rowClone).datepicker(); // Code to fix the problem
}
```

EDIT: When I add the code "$('.date', rowClone).datepicker();". There is a strange problem. 
Seq1: Add Row => Click on textbox of newRow, calender pops up and everything works fine.
Seq2: 1. Click on textbox of original row's textbox, nothing pops up.
 2. Click on document and then try on textbox of original row, then calender pops up.
3. Add new row.
4. now click on textbox of new row, calender never pops up to select the date.

Any help is much appreciated. JSFiddle for the scenario is following:

### http://jsfiddle.net/wAyhm/9/

For working solution Please follow the following link:
[Adding new row, binding of datepicker to cloumn works in weird manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286100/adding-new-row-binding-of-datepicker-to-cloumn-works-in-weird-manner/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rowClone` as the context in the selector and you can grab the `.date` element to apply the datepicker:

```
function addRow(btn) {         
    var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var table = parentRow.parentNode;
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var lastRow = table.rows[rowCount - 1];
    var rowClone = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
    table.appendChild(rowClone);

    $('.date', rowClone).datepicker();
}
```

Comment: Code is not working in another scenario as I have updated the code.

Comment: @Amit, can you post an example on jsfiddle.net that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Amit I think the issue is with the clone. Try this fiddle, it's a bit long winded but works: http://jsfiddle.net/wAyhm/13/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker').on('focusin', '.datepicker', function(e) {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution but couldn't make it work. To be clear, my class was "date" so I replaced datepicker with date ?
And Second, should I place this code in $document.read() or just under the script tag ?